# Terser: prefix all mangled variables and functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, build, terser

I'm working on a single-file script that is meant to be included on pages through a `<script>` tag, it's being built with Vite.js using the Terser minifier.

After making changes I noticed that the built version of my script was suddenly throwing errors whenever I called Google Analytics code.

After doing some digging, I noticed one of the other packages on a site I was including the script on was calling a function called `ga()`. The error is happening because Terser is minifying/mangling a function in my script and naming it `ga()`, which then conflicts with this other function I have no control over.

I *assumed* Terser would have an option to either

- not mangle to a specific name
- prefix all mangled functions

But it doesn't seem to have either.

I've managed to fix the problem by adding the following to my config:

```
    minify: "terser",
    terserOptions: {
      keep_fnames: true,
    },
```

Which stops Terser from mangling ANY function names, but obviously this isn't great as it's wasting a ton of potential for minification.

Is there any way to tell Terser to still mangle all functions, but to do so while also prefixing it with `a_` for example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with regex, [You can check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58835084/webpackterserplugin-mangle-ignores-properties-and-class-names-poor-quality-o) or go to [mangle.properties](https://github.com/terser/terser#mangle-properties-options) for complete documentation.

```
terserOptions: {
    mangle: {
        properties: {
            regex: /(^P1|^p1|^_p1)[A-Z]\w*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This allows me to specify which functions I don't want mangled in terser, but it doesn't help with stopping a function from being named `ga()`, which is the problem I'm having.

Comment: Did you find a fix? I stumbled upon the same issue...

Comment: No solution unfortunately